# How do you search the Ubuntu Software Center from the Unity Dash?

Tags: unity, software-center, unity-dash

Instead of having to open Ubuntu Software Center which is slow, I would like to just open up Dash, and search for the program I'd like to install. How can I make this possible?

Currently I see Applications and Files&Folders results. Is there a way to get a section for "Ubuntu Software Center" ?

Comment: What you're asking for is a unity scope. As far as I know, there is no scope for Software Center.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is unity scope or lens. From my searches online so far I have not found a scope or lens that would allow searching for software.

However, if you are looking for an alternative to Software Center, I recommend you get familiar with lubuntu software center or `apt-cache search` command in terminal. In the last year and half I've only used `apt-cache search some-app-name` to search software and `apt-get install app-name` to install.

If you want something graphical, I've put together a simple script that will allow you to search for software graphically. You can bind this script to a shortcut, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>

```
#!/bin/sh
# Author : Serg Kolo
# Date: Wed Jun  3 09:50 2015
# Description: list available packages graphically
# using apt-cache search and zenity

FILE=~/.apt-search.txt
SEARCHTERM="$(zenity --entry --text='Enter key to search' )"

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        apt-cache search "$SEARCHTERM" | nl >  $FILE
        zenity --text-info  --filename=$FILE 
fi
```